# Perl JSON issue when string starts with [ and not {

Tags: json, perl, hash

Hope some Perl gurus out there can help me out here. Basically my issue is when a JSON string starts with a "[" instead of a "{", Perl doesn't treat the variable as a hash after I use decode_json.

Here's a sample code.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use JSON;

use Data::Dumper;
$string1 = '{"Peti Bar":{"Literature":88,"Mathematics":82,"Art":99},"Foo Bar":{"Literature":67,"Mathematics":97}}';
$string = '[{"ActionID":5,"ActionName":"TEST- 051017"},{"ActionID":10,"ActionName":"Something here"},{"ActionID":13,"ActionName":"Some action"},{"ActionID":141,"ActionName":"Email Reminder"}]';
print "First string that starts with \"{\" below:\n$string1\n\n";
my $w = decode_json $string1;
my $count = keys %$w;
print "printing \$count's value -> $count\n\n";
print "Second string starts with \"[\" below:\n$string\n\n";
my $x = decode_json $string;
my $count2 = keys %$x;
print "printing \$count2's value ->  $count2\n\n";
```

Below is the script output.

[image: <code>Script output</code>]

Both $w and $x works though. It's just I have to use **keys $x** instead of **keys %$x** on the other json string.

Now the issue with using that is I get a **keys on reference is experimental at tests/jsontest.pl** error. It won't stop the script but I'm worried about future compatibility issues.

What's the best way to approach this?

Comment: It's an *array*. `my $count2 = @$x`

Comment: Please don't post images of text. The text itself is far more useful to us.

Comment: it's quite common for a json data structure to be an array of hashes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ref` function to determine what type the reference is. See [`perldoc -f ref`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/ref.html).

```
my $w = decode_json $string1;
my $count = 1;

if( my $ref = ref( $w ) ){
    if( $ref eq 'HASH' ){
        $count = keys %$w;
    }elsif( $ref eq 'ARRAY' ){
        $count = scalar @$w;
    }else{
        die "invalid reference '$ref'\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks shawnhcorey!  That was awesome. Although I used if (ref $w eq 'ARRAY') instead of creating $ref.  Do you foresee an issue with that approach?

Comment: `if( ref( $w ) eq 'ARRAY' )` Include the parenthesis around `$w` for clarity. There is nothing wrong with this. TIMTOWTDI.

Comment: @user: Shawn's approach avoids calculating `ref $w` twice.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Helped a lot!